# React - Updating UI based on users subscription

Tags: reactjs, authorization

I have a React app which has specific fields visible depending on the user's subscription.

On page load the subscription is checked via an API request, however I wanted to check is it a valid concern that someone could modify that response to show elements of the UI that they shouldn't see?

How is this generally handled?

Of course, I could do some additional server side checks, but wondering if I can do something on the the front end that can help?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you will need to have server checks. The front end checks can easily be modified by the user using his browser developer tools.

Yes, he can view things he is not supposed to. You are to also make sure that you send only necessary details on the API request, because he can view the API response body using the developer tools too.

All the best.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a token from back-end and check the validity in the front-end with a client secret. so if anyone modified your response they can't edit it without the correct secret key.